# Clearing Mesh of Graph

Tags: visualization, data-modeling, data-visualization

If we do the information visualization of documents, the graph generation across multiple documents often forms a mesh. Now to get a clear picture it is easy to form them with minimum data load and thus summarization is a good thing. But if the document load becomes 
million then with summarization also the graph forms a big mesh. 
I am bit perplexed how to clear the mesh. Reading and working round http://www.jerrytalton.net/research/Talton04SSMSA.report/Talton04SSMSA.pdf is not coming much help, as data is huge.

If any learned members may kindly help me out.

Regards,
SK

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about creating a graph or network of the documents? For example, you could have a network of documents linked by their citations, by having shared authors, by having the same terms appearing in them, etc. This isn't generally called a mesh problem, instead it is an automatic graph layout problem.

You need either [better layout algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing) or to do some kind of clustering and reduction. There are many clustering algorithms you can use, for example Wakita & Tsurumi's:

- Ken Wakita and Toshiyuki Tsurumi. 2007. Finding community structure in mega-scale social networks: [extended abstract]. Proc. 16th international conference on World Wide Web (WWW '07). 1275-1276. DOI=[10.1145/1242572.1242805](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1242572.1242805).

One that is particularly targeted at reducing complexity through "graph summarization" is Navlakha et al. 2008:

- Saket Navlakha, Rajeev Rastogi, and Nisheeth Shrivastava. 2008. Graph summarization with bounded error. Proc. 2008 ACM SIGMOD international conference on Management of data (SIGMOD '08). 419-432. DOI=[10.1145/1376616.1376661](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1376616.1376661).

You could also check out my latest paper, which replaces common repeating patterns in the network with representative glyphs:

- Dunne, C. & Shneiderman, B. 2013. Motif simplification: improving network visualization readability with fan, connector, and clique glyphs. Proc. 2013 SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems (CHI '13). [PDF](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~cdunne/hcil/pubs/Dunne13Motifsimplification_improving.pdf).

Here's an example picture of the reduction possible:

[image: Dunne & Shneiderman's motif simplification]